# Another problem updating flavour of linux (2)

Tags: vertical-alignment, ubuntu, debian

I have several books made with Tex (pdf made with XeLaTeX) and I have encountered a problem updating my software.

Currently I have installed texlive-full + kile. The distribution used is Debian 7.
I tried to upgrade to other distributions like Ubuntu in its flavors and other derivatives as LinuxMint, KXStudio, etc.
The result of migration has always been the same: the documents do not produce an identical pdf.
Deputy minimum tex file and pdf conducted in Debian and xBuntu / derivatives.

I make the compilation Kile with XeLaTeX

[image: Pantallazo de barra de herramientas de kile]

*File .tex:*

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book} % libro impreso
\usepackage[right=1.8cm,left=2.6cm,top=2.6cm,bottom=1.8cm,headsep=0.6cm,footskip=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed} 
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setlength{\headheight}{17pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}
            {6dd} %espacio entre la leyenda del capitulo y el titulo del capitulo
            {\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt} %margen izquierdo del titulo
            {-20pt} %espacio antes de la leyenda capítulo
            {3cc} %espacio despues del titulo del capitulo
\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em} % entrada párrafo 1.5 cuadratines
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt} % separación entre párrafos
\linespread{1} % interlinea
\mdfdefinestyle{Marco}{%
    linecolor=black,
    outerlinewidth=0.25dd,
    roundcorner=6pt,
    innertopmargin=6dd,
    innerbottommargin=6dd,
    innerrightmargin=6dd,
    innerleftmargin=6dd,
    backgroundcolor=white
    skipbelow=0,
    skipabove=0}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Posiciones del paciente}

\section{Decúbito supino}

\noindent\begin{wrapfigure}[9]{l}[0mm]{54mm}
\vspace{-5mm}
\includegraphics[height=40mm, keepaspectratio]{imatges/4-1.png}
\end{wrapfigure}
\\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ 
\indent 


\section{Decúbito prono}

\noindent\begin{wrapfigure}[9]{l}[0mm]{54mm}
\vspace{-5mm}
\includegraphics[height=40mm, keepaspectratio]{imatges/4-2.png}
\end{wrapfigure}
\\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ 
\indent 


\section{Decúbito lateral}

\noindent\begin{wrapfigure}[9]{l}[0mm]{54mm}
\vspace{-5mm}
\includegraphics[height=40mm, keepaspectratio]{imatges/4-3.png}
\end{wrapfigure}
\\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\
\indent 


\begin{mdframed}[style=Marco]

\textbf{Zonas delicadas}

\vspace{1\baselineskip}

\begin{itemize}
\item \textit{Hueco poplíteo:} Situada en la región posterior de la rodilla

\item \textit{Triángulo de Scarpa:} Espacio triangular en la región de la ingle, cuyos lados están formados por el ligamento inguinal, músculo sartorio y el primer aductor.

\item \textit{Pliegue de codo:} Zona entre el brazo y el antebrazo (parte anterior).
\end{itemize}
\end{mdframed}

\newpage

\end{document}
```

I detected another problem because of the diff.

The space between the text and the list differs in the version of Ubuntu.
Do you know how I can fix this problem?

[image: Recorte comparativo]

Keep in mind that I can only rewrite the preamble because I have a lot of books made.

It would be desirable not having to put Debian libraries in each book.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: The operating system is not relevant but you presumably have different versions of one or more latex packages. (of the ones I see in your example I would guess mdframed most likely to have been updated in a way that could change spacing) If you still have access to the old setup (or an old log file) add \listfiles to your document and compare version numbers (or post the result into your question)

Comment: That said since you have `\vspace{1\baselineskip}` so a full baselineskip of space in addition to the space usually placed abve a list, I'd expect you to get the larger space you show.

Comment: Hello.

After several tests over as the proposals made by you, I have found that the error occurs because of the box and the version change.

In the Debian version: When the vspace is inside the mdframed: no action.

But acting when not inside the mdframed.

The Ubuntu version: always act properly.

Therefore, when changing the version I need to malfunction, to avoid redoing all the work.

Is there any way to tell vspace not acting when it is in a mdframed?

For example with an if statement?

Answer (score 1):

I have found de solution:

```
\newcommand{\LineasBlancas}[1]{%
  \ifinmdframed \else \vspace{#1\baselineskip} \fi%
}
\newif\ifinmdframed
\AtBeginEnvironment{mdframed}{\inmdframedtrue}
```

Comment: Could you explain the solution in more detail?

Comment: In version Debian seems to malfunction vspace within mdframed.
The Ubuntu version works fine.
With this solution we get also malfunction in the Ubuntu version.
This way we keep the format of the books already written and make only a small change for the books that interest us.